# Page transition on page load

Tags: jquery, css

I have to create page transition/animation on page load. The effect should be like an overlay/div crosses the full screen from right to left

So far I got to the point where it crosses from right to left and stops but I need it to go from right to left and leave screen to the left.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<style>
@keyframes slideInFromLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.transition {

    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;

    background: #333;
    padding: 30px;
}
</style>
<div class="transition"></div>
```

I made a little picture to ilustrate my desired outcome. Div comes in from the right and leaves out to the left
 [blog]: https://ibb.co/yPJK7Tp "click here for picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the transition finishes at `-100%`.

Since you've added some padding then you should increase the value a little bit (something like `-110%`)

See This Example:

I've added `forwards` to animation to make stick in the end after finishing animation.

```css
   @keyframes slideInFromLeft {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-110%);
      }
    }

    .transition {
      animation: slideInFromLeft 2s ease-out forwards ;
      background: #333;
      padding: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="transition"></div>
```